# Adding CSS to each cell for a column in Slick grid based on cell value

Tags: jquery, css, slickgrid

Based on cell value, I want to apply a CSS class to that cell in slick grid.

I am using following code on the column

```
{
  id: 'deptType',
  name: 'Department Type',
  field: 'dept_type',
  sortable: true,
  formatter: function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
                  if(value === 'red'){
                      return '<div style="width:100%; padding:0; margin:0" class ="red">' + value + '</div>';
                  }
                  return '<div style="width:100%; padding:0; margin:0" class ="green">' + value + '</div>';
             }
}
```

Though this code is working. I wonder if there is a better approach to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine to me, you can more centralize styling and potentially improve CSS rendering speed using the following code, where you do not use HTML property `style` but `class` instead.

```
.red, .green {
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.red {
color: red;
}
.green {
color: green;
}

{
  id: 'deptType',
  name: 'Department Type',
  field: 'dept_type',
  sortable: true,
  formatter: function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
                  if(value === 'red'){
                      return '<div class ="red">' + value + '</div>';
                  }
                  return '<div class ="green">' + value + '</div>';
             }
}
```