# Setting SlickGrid cell styling based on cell value

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

How can I use SlickGrid to change the style of a cell (lets say the text color) based on the value of the cell? IE if cell value is below 50, make it green, otherwise make it red.

I've looked into `getItemMetadata`, but it doesn't seem to have a way to set cell specific stylings, and it also doesnt have a way to dynamic determine the class based on cell value.

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339901/adding-css-to-each-cell-for-a-column-in-slick-grid-based-on-cell-value) offering possible solution. Also, [setCellCssStyles](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#setCellCssStyles) might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've generally handled cell level styling in the past. Obviously, you must be using a dataview for this to work. I just keep this at the bottom of my grid setup, immediately above where I render the grid. Hope this help!

```
//Put this in your style sheet. 
.greenCSSclass {color:green;}
.redCSSclass {color:red;}

dataView.getItemMetadata = metadata(dataView.getItemMetadata);
var redCells= {}; 
var greenCells= {};          
function metadata(old_metadata_provider) {
      return function (row) {
          var item = this.getItem(row);
          var ret = (old_metadata_provider(row) || {});            
          if (item) {
              ret.cssClasses = (ret.cssClasses || '');
              //Include any row level CSS rules here by editing ret.cssClasses

              //Clear previous CSS rule for this cell.
              if (redCells.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
                  delete redCells[row];
              }
              if (greenCells.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
                  delete greenCells[row];
              }

              //Evaluate the value here and add to either map
              if (item.columnName < 50 ) {
                  if (!greenCells[row]) {
                      greenCells[row] = {};
                  }
                  greenCells[row]["columnName"] = "greenCSSclass";
              } else {
                  if (!redCells[row]) {
                      redCells[row] = {};
                  }
                  redCells[row]["columnName"] = "redCSSclass";
              }

              //Set Cell CSS. 
              grid.setCellCssStyles("greenCells", greenCells);
              grid.setCellCssStyles("redCells", redCells);
          }
          return ret;
      }
  }
```